# Setup Permanent 301 Redirects after moving to Https

Tags: htaccess, ssl

i moved my site from http to https 
now i want to redirect the user into the new url but evry time i'm trying to edit .htaccess file i'm getting an error

this is the working file content where xxxz is site name

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxz\.qa$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xxxz\.qa$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]    {32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/xxxz\.com\.qa" [R=301,L]
```

what i'm trying to edit is to add the following code in the top of the file as i read

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxz.com.qa [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xxxz.com.qa [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xxxz.com.qa/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

but its not working so what do u think

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, I assume you have taken a look on the numerous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049820/use-htaccess-to-redirect-http-to-https) as given here?!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxz.com.qa [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xxxz.com.qa [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xxxz.com.qa/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
> ```

This will result in a redirect loop as it will repeatedly redirect `https://www.xxxz.com.qa/<url>` to `https://www.xxxz.com.qa/<url>` again and again...

If you want to redirect from HTTP then you need to check that the request was for HTTP before redirecting to HTTPS. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

No need for the `NC` flag, as you are simply matching everything anyway.

---

However, this conflicts with the existing directives at the end of your file:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxz\.qa$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xxxz\.qa$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]    {32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
> RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/xxxz\.com\.qa" [R=301,L]
> ```

These directives should probably be deleted. (Fortunately, they probably aren't doing anything anyway - because they are *after* the WordPress front-controller.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way for setting up Permanent 301 Redirects is by editing .htaccess with the required redirection code. Follow these steps:

1. Open your cPanel account.
2. Click on **File Manager** under **Files** section.
3. Click on **public_html** directory in the left sidebar.
4. Search for the **.htaccess** file. Right-click on it. Click on **Edit**.
5. A pop up box will appear. Click on **Edit**.
6. A new tab will be opened. Here, you have to add the
   redirect code. For example, your old page is
   https://yoursite.com/old-page.htm, and the new page is
   https://yoursite.com/new-page.htm. In this case, the redirect code
   will be:

   ```
   Redirect 301 /old-page.htm/ /new-page.htm
   ```

You can find more information about these steps [right here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-setup-a-permanent-301-redirect-from-one-file-to-another-using-htaccess/).

Comment: You can't use a mod_alias `Redirect` to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS - you need to use mod_rewrite (if using `.htaccess`). But since mod_rewrite directives are already being used by the WordPress front-controller, you shouldn't really be using `Redirect` for _any_ redirects.